# Using React with API calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , f.default) is not a function`

`items component`

```
class Items extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
  itemList: [],
};
this.fetchItems = this.fetchItems.bind(this);
}
fetchItems(){
const url ="url" #api goes here;
this.setState({data: utilAPI(url)});
}

render(){
  return(
      <div className="jumbotron mx-auto jumbo-about">
        {this.fetchItems()}
        {console.log(this.state)}
        <p>{this.state.itemList}</p>
      </div>
    );
}
}

export default Items;
```

`item utils`

```
export const fetchItemsAPI = (url) => {
fetch(url).then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    }).then(data=>{
      return({
        champion: data.id,
        name:data.name
      });
    });
};
```

I am not sure if the request is going through because the api works when i use it. I am not sure if the util request is good and i am not sure how i can test it.

Comment: promises don't return values, but other promises :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return the result of the fetch call. Then you use it to set the state

```
const fetchItemsAPI = (url) => {
  return fetch(url).then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    });
};

fetchItems(){
  const url ="url" #api goes here;
  fetchItemsAPI(url)
    .then(data => {
      //Here you can manipulate the json data
      this.setState({data});
    });  
}
```

Comment: I see the mistakes I made, I tried to type it in the chrome console and getting a CORS error.

Comment: That's something you'll have to solve in the back-end. This should work when you have the CORS issue sorted out. Note you can also add a `catch` callback to update the state in case of errors. Always remember that promises don't return values, just other promises that resolve to those values, like WillomGfx said in his comment